# Build gcc without a c compiler

Tags: gcc

Is it possible to build gcc without a c compiler already on the machine?  If so, how?

Comment: You can always get a binary... If you're getting into such considerations, you usually are pretty screwed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you're talking about is known as [bootstrapping a compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)).

Typically this is done by cross-compiling the compiler on another machine for the target architecture. You can find some background [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/build.html) and [here](http://www.kegel.com/crosstool/current/doc/crosstool-howto.html). It's not a trivial process, though. If your target isn't architecture that GCC already supports then you've got a *lot* of work ahead of you.

Comment: I remember reading some old `gcc` installation instructions that were about building a minimal compiler with `as` and using it to build the real `gcc`.

Comment: I've always thought that bootstrapping a compiler on a new architecture would be fun. Of course, designing a processor ISA and implementing it in discrete logic or FPGAs sounds like a lot of fun, too...  *smile*  Oh, if I only had free time...

Answer (score 1):

Wow - I'm only 99.9% sure but no, no I really don't believe you can.

That said it might be worth asking on SO.